# jQuery trying to show next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am very new to JavaScript and jQuery. Can you please give me some guidance as to why I can't the next element to show.

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="questionContainer">

    <div class="question">
         How much storage do you need?
    </div>

     <div class="answers">
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <label>
                     <input type="radio" id="storage">1GB or less
                 </label>
             </li>

             <li>
                 <label>
                     <input type="radio" id="storage">More than 1GB
                 </label>
             </li>  
         </ul>
     </div>

     <div class="btnContainer">
         <div class="next">
             <a class="btnNext">Next</a>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now I have four of these `.questionContainer` which each contain the same html markup structure, I am hiding all but the first and when next is clicked I want the next question to show and the current to hide. I have attempted it with this javascript

**JavaScript**

```
(function(){

    var Questions = {

        init : function() {

            var container = $('.questionContainer');

            container.not(':first').hide();

            container.find('a.btnNext').on('click', function(){

                $(this).closest('.questionContainer').next().siblings().show();
            })
        }

    };

    Questions.init();

})();
```

The problem is that instead of showing only the next `.questionContainer` on click, it shows them all. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `siblings()` method you're explicitly selecting all. Just do:

```
$(this).closest('.questionContainer').next().show();
```

Comment: I just figured it out, I had `<br>` tags after each of my `<div class="questionContainer">`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I had removed those. Using breaks for layout isn't good practice, especially when your preceding element (a div, in this case) is already block-level.